# Java overloading with variable length arguments

Tags: java, overloading

Why there is no compile error in this code:

```
public class OverloadingVarArgs
{
    public void fun1(int... b)
    {
        System.out.println("int");
    }
    public void fun1(long... a)
    {
        System.out.println("long");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OverloadingVarArgs obj = new OverloadingVarArgs();
        obj.fun1();
    }

}
```

But this code gives compile error!

```
public class OverloadingVarArgs
{
    public void fun1(int... b)
    {
        System.out.println("int");
    }
    public void fun1(boolean... a)
    {
        System.out.println("boolean");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OverloadingVarArgs obj = new OverloadingVarArgs();
        obj.fun1();
    }
}
```

I believe there should be compile error in both the case, but this is not so.

Comment: Please post the compile error in full.

Comment: The error for the second one he is getting is:

`error: reference to fun1 is ambiguous, both method fun1(int...) in Main and method fun1(boolean...) in Main match
    obj.fun1();
       ^
1 error`

Comment: @Sid Then both code examples would have to result in a compiler error since both times the methods are ambiguous.

Comment: In the first one, I believe the concept of automatic broader casting comes into picture, as int and long are essentially numbers and could be casted into each other.  Boolean, on the other hand, seems to be an entirely unrelated primitive type.  Remember, varargs means 0 or more occurrences.

Comment: in Eclipse Indigo, I am getting compiler error in both the cases, for being ambiguous, because both int[] and boolean[] will be referred by not passing any arguement. JRE1.7

Comment: @saikumar, the first one actually worked for me with output 'int'

Comment: @saikumar On the command line, with `javac` from JDK 8, I get the errors as described.

Comment: You can use `public void fun1(Object... o)` and check their instance with `instanceof`

Comment: @Eun That would not be a nice solution. I'd much rather use generics if we were going to use `Object` type.

Answer (score 9):

The rules for selecting the correct overloaded method are as follows:

- Primitive widening uses the smallest method argument possible
- Wrapper type cannot be widened to another Wrapper type
- You can Box from int to Integer and widen to Object but no to Long
- Widening beats Boxing, Boxing beats Var-args.
- You can Box and then Widen (An int can become Object via Integer)
- You cannot Widen and then Box (An int cannot become Long)
- You cannot combine var-args, with either widening or boxing

Have a look at that last rule. You can *not* combine widening or boxing with variable length arguments. That means that the types can not be manipulated in any way and you have to perform the comparison as is. `int` and `long` can be compared, no problem and the compiler can deduce that `int` is the smaller of the two. As per the first rule, it will go for the smallest method argument possible, hence it has worked out the correct (and only) route to a method.

However, when you get to `boolean` and `int`, there exists no comparison method between the two because of Java's *strong typing*. With no knowledge of which type is smallest, the compiler has absolutely no clue which method you mean.

**More Visual Example**

Let's take it step by step from the perspective of the compiler. First, with `int` and `long`.

**int and long**

*Step 1 - Checking if the parameters match any arguments and if so, which one it matches exactly*

Well, `varargs` means that you can pass `0` to many arguments. In this case, you've elected to pass `0` arguments, hence your call matches both the `int` type and the `long` type.

*Step 2 - Attempt to autobox or widen. This should help it work out which one to go for*

You're using varargs, so the compiler knows it can't do this, as per the final rule.

*Step 3 - Attempt to work out which type is smallest*

The compiler is able to compare the type `int` with the type `long`. From this, it works out that the `int` is the smallest type.

*Step 4 - Make the call*

With the knowledge that `int` is the smallest type, it then passes the value to the method for execution.

Okay, and now let's do the same thing with `boolean` and `int`.

**boolean and int**

*Step 1 - Checking if the parameters match any arguments and if so, which one it matches exactly*

Same story. You've passed nothing so match both arguments.

*Step 2 - Attempt to autobox or widen. This should help it work out which one to go for*

As above, you're not permitted to do this because you used varargs.

*Step 3 - Attempt to work out which type is smallest*

This is the crucial difference. Here, the types are *not* comparable. This means that the compiler doesn't know which method you want to call by your parameters *or* by the smallest type. Ergo, it has been unable to work out the correct route.

*Step 4 - Make the call*

Without the knowledge of which method to call, it can not continue execution and throws the appropriate exception.

Answer (score 5):

In your second example, the compiler is unable to determine the **most specific method** to invoke.

The gory details are explained in [**the language spec**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), but essentially if two variable-arity (var-arg) methods are being compared, then if Method A could accept the arguments passed to Method B, but not the other way around, then Method B is most specific.

In your first example, the [**rules of primitive sub-typing**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10) are applied, which are:

> double ><sub>1</sub> float
>
> float ><sub>1</sub> long
>
> long ><sub>1</sub> int
>
> int ><sub>1</sub> char
>
> int ><sub>1</sub> short
>
> short ><sub>1</sub> byte
>
> <sub>(*Where ><sub>1</sub> means 'direct supertype of'*)</sub>

Here we can see that an `int` is more specific than a `long`, so your `fun1(int... b)` method is chosen.

In the second example, the compiler is choosing between an `int` and `boolean`. There is no sub-type relationship between those primiritve types, therefore there is no most specific method and "*the method invocation is ambiguous, and a compile-time error occurs.*" (last line in 15.12.2.5).

Answer (score 4):

When you have `int` and `long` (comparable types), the smallest will be used by default, which is `int` (since you're not passing an argument) - I think it's because `int` *can* be widen to `long` but `long` cannot (unless you *explicitly* cast it), the compiler will select the lowest precision type.

But when you have `boolean` and `int`, the comparison cannot be done and you'll get

```
The method fun1(int[]) is ambiguous for the type OverloadingVarArgs
```

Comment: So you're saying because the types are comparable, the compiler can resolve which method is being called by selecting the type with the lowest precision? As opposed to the incompatibility between `boolean` and `int`?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. [This IDEOne](http://ideone.com/N3AkQ4) shows the same effect between `float` and `int`. +1. Excellent catch, as usual!